# SSL certificate Gitlab error while building pipeline

Tags: github, ssl, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have pushsing to a project that is in gitlab and from today I am getting this error while the pipeline deploys

fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/projectut/project.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

I see the error inside Gitlab build section.

Is this an error of my git user or somethng related to the project configuration?

Thank you in advance

That the deployment of the pipeline in Gitlab finishes

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue and then I followed the recommendation gitlab released.
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/production/-/issues/17265

Basically I had to reboot my runner and it started to work after that.

Hopefully this will do the same for you.